# asignar variable dentro de un callback a variable global

Tags: java, android, callback

tengo una funcion en Java que envia una peticion HTTP a un servidor y me gustaria almacenar una respuesta fuera del callback.

El problema es que al hacerlo, me sale un json vacio. He estado mirando y he visto que puede ser porque los callbacks se hacen en otro hilo distinto, pero no lo tengo muy claro.

¿Sabría alguien aclararme las dudas? Gracias de antemano

```
JSONObject jsonWeather = new JSONObject();
public JSONObject requestWeatherlocation(double latitude, double longitude, Activity activity) {
    EnvironmentVariables env = new EnvironmentVariables();

    String url = env.getOpenWeatherMapUrlWeather() + "?appid=" + env.getOpenWeatherMapApi() + "&lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
    Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    jsonWeather = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    });
    return jsonWeather;
}
```

*****ACTUALIZACION*****
He añadido el metodo:

```
public void setJsonWeather(JSONObject jsonWeather){
    this.jsonWeather = jsonWeather;
}
```

Y en el metodo `onResponse`, el  try he añadido:

```
 try {
     jsonWeather = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
     setJsonWeather(jsonWeather);
 } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tomar en cuenta que la respuesta del Callback se realiza de forma asíncrona, por lo tanto, llamar el siguiente proceso debe realizarse dentro de `onResponse()` en caso de tener una respuesta por parte del servidor o dentro de `onFailure()` en caso de presentarse algún error al realizar la petición.

Por ejemplo, al obtener el json puedes llamar el proceso que realiza el parseo de los datos:

```
...
 ...
 public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    jsonWeather = new JSONObject(response.body().string());

                    //*Realiza el siguiente proceso.   
                    parseaInformacion(jsonWeather); 


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
   ...
   ...
```

Comment: Y dentro del metodo parseaInformacion ya puedo igualar jsonWeather con la variable global verdad?

Comment: Así es @Angel, en ese punto ya tendrá valor jsonWeather.

Comment: Pues el resultado es el mismo.. Te he actualizado el comentario principal

Comment: Bueno ahí  es importante asegura que la petición obtuvo algo, si obtienes algo en response.body().string() ? de lo contrario lo que es incorrecto es la petición, tal vez la url falta algún parámetro, en este caso debes revisar ahí.